# parse-server-example project no longer working

Tags: node.js, npm-install, parse-server, heroku-cli

I have been using this [parse-server-example](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example.git) project from GitHub many times in the past, as a starting point for my own (Heroku) projects.

But now I keep hitting problems when running `npm install`.
With warning or error messages like this one:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

or towards the end:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
9 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/ node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.  js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/    node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Documents/Heroku/myapp/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

What is the right way to handle this ?

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the `requests` depreciation message for now.

In order to handle the error you shared remove `"kerberos": "~0.0.x"` from the `package.json` then run

```
npm install
```

This should fix the build